# Show/hide DIV based on selected radio button input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I'm trying to toggle multiple DIVs that have the same data attribute value based on the value of the select radio button.

But I'm not sure what's wrong with my code below.

By default, the first radio button is always selected on load, how do I trigger it to show the 3 DIVs of the matching value?

Mark-up:

```
<nav id="gift-subs-options">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="subscription-period" value="3mths" checked />
                <span class="period">3 months</span>                        
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="subscription-period" value="6mths" />
                <span class="period">6 months</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="subscription-period" value="12mths" />
                <span class="period">12 months</span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="prices" data-period="3mths">A 1</div>
<div class="prices" data-period="6mths">B 1</div>
<div class="prices" data-period="12mths">C 1</div>

<div class="prices" data-period="3mths">A 2</div>
<div class="prices" data-period="6mths">B 2</div>
<div class="prices" data-period="12mths">C 2</div>

<div class="prices" data-period="3mths">A 2</div>
<div class="prices" data-period="6mths">B 2</div>
<div class="prices" data-period="12mths">C 3</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".prices").hide();

    $("input[name$='subscription-period']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $(".prices[data-period]='" + test + "'").show();
    });
});
```

Fiddle if you wanted to test:
http://jsfiddle.net/calebo/cRKwY/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have given is **syntactically wrong**. You need to give this way:

```
$(".prices[data-period='" + test + "']").show();
```

Also **hide** other `div`s before refreshing.

```
$(".prices").hide();
```

**Full Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".prices").hide();

    $("input[name$='subscription-period']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $(".prices").hide();
        $(".prices[data-period='" + test + "']").show();
    });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/Lgk7B/

Answer (score 0):

Read [**attribute equals selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3sdk8/1)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".prices").hide();

    $("input[name$='subscription-period']").change(function () {
        var test = this.value;
        $(".prices").hide();
        $(".prices[data-period='" + test + "']").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".prices").hide();

    $("input[name='subscription-period']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $(".prices[data-period ='" + test + "']").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".prices").hide();

   var defaultval=$("input[name$='subscription-period']").val();
   $(".prices[data-period='" + defaultval + "'").show();
   $("input[name$='subscription-period']").change(function() {
      $(".prices").hide();
      var test = $(this).val();
      $(".prices[data-period='" + test + "'").show();
  });
});
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/cRKwY/2/

Comment: It would seem that this doesnt work in firefox, but works in chrome and other browsers. :(