# Show/hide DIV based on selected with data-toggle="buttons" input radio button bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, hide, show

Have checked almost every possible solution with java script and Jquery here. But not able to find the solution for this. Almost every solution working with your "data-toggle="buttons". But I need with data-toggle="buttons".

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="btn-group btn-toggle"  data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="subscription-period" value="3mths" > 3 months
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="subscription-period" value="6mths" > 6 months
    </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="subscription-period" value="12mths" > 12 months
    </label>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="prices" data-period="3mths">A 1</div>
<div class="prices" data-period="6mths">B 1</div>
<div class="prices" data-period="12mths">C 1</div>

<div class="prices" data-period="3mths">A 2</div>
<div class="prices" data-period="6mths">B 2</div>
<div class="prices" data-period="12mths">C 2</div>

<div class="prices" data-period="3mths">A 2</div>
<div class="prices" data-period="6mths">B 2</div>
<div class="prices" data-period="12mths">C 3</div>
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".prices").hide();

    $("input[name$='subscription-period']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $(".prices").hide();
        $(".prices[data-period='" + test + "']").show();
    });
});
```

here taken reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419276/show-hide-div-based-on-selected-radio-button-input?newreg=f0f145c6aa5c4f75a83899e5579b87de)

you can check live [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b3m2T/). Have added both with data-toggle="buttons" and with out data-toggle="buttons"

Comment: What do you want exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Update your jquery like below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".prices").hide();
$(".btn-default").click(function(){
  var test = $(this).find("input[name$='subscription-period']").val();
    $(".prices").hide();
    $(".prices[data-period='" + test + "']").show();
});

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b3m2T/2/)