# change table header upon selecting of ratio button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with two radio buttons. One radio button is checked by default but if the other radio button is checked, without pressing a button, I want the header in my table to change.

Here are some snippets:

```html
<table class="table table-sm table-secondary" style="margin-bottom: 0">
  <thead style="background-color: #cb5797">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center">Duration (min)</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center hideme" data-period="outdoor">
        Speed1
      </th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center">Incline (%)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
    <input
      type="radio"
      name="environment"
      id="indoor"
      value="indoor"
      checked="checked"
    />
    Indoor
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="environment" id="outdoor" value="outdoor" />
    Outdoor
  </label>
</div>
```

I have tried to get this example to work but was not successful
[Show/hide DIV based on selected with data-toggle="buttons" input radio button bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007300/show-hide-div-based-on-selected-with-data-toggle-buttons-input-radio-button-bo)

FYI, I'm new to javascript, therefore please provide plenty of details with your answer.

Comment: Do you want pure javascript or JQuery like the post you linked?

Comment: Try checking out Javascript's `onclick` event.

Answer (score 0):

Every radio button (or checkbox) has an event called [onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp). For radiobuttons and checkboxes, the onchange event occurs when the checked state has been changed. You can create two functions and add them as in the snippet below.

Since your table header has the `data-period="outdoor"` attribute, I'm guessing this is what you want to change. This can be done using the [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) functions. I also added a bit of code to change the header background-color, for learning purposes.

```js
function toggleIndoor() {
  console.log("toggleIndoor changed!");

  // Change the header data-period attribute
  var headerCell = document.getElementById("tochange");
  headerCell.setAttribute("data-period", "indoor");
  printHeaderDataPeriod();

  // Change the header color
  var tableHeader = document.getElementById("table-head");
  tableHeader.style.backgroundColor = "#cb5797";
}

function toggleOutdoor() {
  console.log("toggleOutdoor changed!");
  var headerCell = document.getElementById("tochange");

  headerCell.setAttribute("data-period", "outdoor");
  printHeaderDataPeriod();

  // Change the header color
  var tableHeader = document.getElementById("table-head");
  tableHeader.style.backgroundColor = "#aa00bb";
}

function printHeaderDataPeriod() {
  var headerCell = document.getElementById("tochange");
  var headerAttr = headerCell.getAttribute("data-period");
  console.log("Table has data-period: " + headerAttr);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
<input type="radio" name="environment" id="indoor" value="indoor" checked="checked" onchange="toggleIndoor()"> Indoor
</label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
<input type="radio" name="environment" id="outdoor" value="outdoor" onchange="toggleOutdoor()"> Outdoor
</label>
</div>

<table class="table table-sm table-secondary" style="margin-bottom: 0">
  <thead style="background-color: #cb5797" id="table-head">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center">Duration (min)</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center hideme" data-period="outdoor" id="tochange">Speed1</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center">Incline (%)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

If you want to change the header style (color, size etc.), it can be easily done using the `setAttribute` function or doing `element.style.<css-property-name> = <value>`, once you got your element by class or by id. Stack overflow has thousands of question like this, about triggering or changing element properties using java-script.

Cheers!